# Creating custom rectangles for SF features

Tags: r, extents, sf, loop

I am trying to create a custom rectangle for each point in my df. I am using two functions to loop through each feature and write a new polygon output. I would like one SF data frame with each of the point geometries replaced with the polygon geometries.

Below is an example of my code so far.

```
sfc = st_sfc(st_point(c(3,4)),st_point(c(5,6)), st_point(c(10,11)))
st_geometry(sfc)
st_geometry(df) <- sfc


#Creating the bounding boxes for each plot
rect_around_point <- function(x,xsize,ysize){
  bbox <- st_bbox(x)
  bbox <- bbox +c(xsize/2,ysize/2,-xsize/2,-ysize/2)
  y = st_as_sfc(bbox)
  return(as.data.frame(y))
}

plot_bbox <- NA

# loop through each plot point and create a polygon 
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  plot_bbox[i] <- rect_around_point(df[i,],5,5)
}

## These lines of code are where my thoughts are going but I cannot seem to pull it together
geoList = do.call(rbind, plot_bbox)
df_geolist <- as.data.frame(geoList)
st_polygon(list(df_geolist))
```

Comment: There is a `squareBuffer` function in the spatialEco package, that supports variable buffers, that would do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(sf)
sfc = st_sfc(st_point(c(3,4)),st_point(c(5,6)), st_point(c(10,11)))

#Creating the bounding boxes for each plot
rect_around_point <- function(x,xsize,ysize){
  bbox <- st_bbox(x)
  bbox <- bbox + c(xsize/2,ysize/2,-xsize/2,-ysize/2)
  y = st_as_sfc(bbox)
  return(y)
}

# loop through each plot point and create a polygon 
plot_bbox <- lapply(sfc, rect_around_point, xsize = 5, ysize = 5)

geoList = do.call(c, plot_bbox)
df_geolist <- st_as_sf(geoList)
```

Another shorter option if your rectangles are squares

```r
library(sf)
sfc = st_sfc(st_point(c(3,4)),st_point(c(5,6)), st_point(c(10,11)))
sfc = st_buffer(sfc, 5)

rect_around_point <- function(x)  st_as_sfc(st_bbox(x))

plot_bbox <- lapply(sfc, rect_around_point)

geoList = do.call(c, plot_bbox)
df_geolist <- st_as_sf(geoList)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The second option is what I need. Many thanks!